# Looking for name of a YA sci-fi novel about VR

Tags: story-identification

Read this story probably sometime back in the ealy-mid 90s about, I believe, a brother and sister who were VR video game designers.  All I can really remember about it at this point is that something went wrong with one of their games, some kind of virus, and they split their time between the VR world and the real world trying to track down who was responsible.

New Information:  Thinking about it some more, I'm pretty sure I remember getting the book through one of the Scholastic book fair magazines.  I'm also starting to feel like 'game' was in the title, but I'm not really sure about that....

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. We have [a number of identification requests about people getting lost in games](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=game+[story-identification]+is%3Aquestion), perhaps you can find your answer among them?

Comment: @SQB No, I dug around quite a bit before posting and saw nothing that looked like it matched.  Though I have remembered that I'm pretty sure I got the book through a scholastic book fair magazine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!  It's called Gemini Game by Michael Scott!  Yes!

> At 14, twins Liz and BJ are smart gamemakers whose high-tech computer games sell in millions. But when their game Night's Castle becomes infected with a virus they are in trouble...